# Unable to process mysql_set_charset variable

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I'm struggling to get the right encoding output on a site I'm developing. But when I use the `mysql_set_charset` function I get the encoding on the site right.

But the strange thing - after using this function - is that I can't process variables right. With right I mean that example the following code doesn't work (which it does when I don't use the `mysql_set_charset` function):

```
$replace = array("å", "ä", "ö");
$with = array("a", "a", "o");

$test = str_replace($repalce, $with, $test);
$test = strtolower($test);
```

connect.php

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
    mysql_select_db("****", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

How come this happen and how should I fix it?

Comment: Have you made sure that you also use the correct encoding on your frontend too?

Comment: You have a typo `$repalce` instead of `$replace` in the line `$test = str_replace($repalce, $with, $test);
`

Comment: Damn, embarrassing. Thank you for sharp eyes!

Comment: @Fredrik If this was the issue then copy/past my comment as an answer to this question otherwise ignore this comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_set_charset` function, as can be read on the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php):

> Sets the default character set for the current connection.

There is absolutely no relation between the use of `mysql_set_charset` and the use of variables on your PHP script, as to  `mysql_set_charset` influence their values.

---

As suggested on the question comments, by @Nacereddine, the most likely issue that you're experiencing is the typo on your code:

```
$test = str_replace($repalce, $with, $test);
```

**Should be:**

```
$test = str_replace($replace, $with, $test);
```

---

The best option while developing, is to have PHP displaying errors, warnings, etc to allow you to see immediately what's wrong, thus preventing wrong conclusions:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

*This will show you all errors, added it at the very top of your file.*

You can read about it at the [PHP: Runtime Configuration - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)